# expression evaluation in C++ using LinkedList

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Assume given 2 polynomial expressions, I am trying to code a program which performs 3 different operations: 1.match(equality) 2.sum(addition) and 3.dot(multiplication).

```
class Node
{
public:
int coef;
int expo;
Node *next;
Node(int coef=0, int expo=0, Node *next=NULL)
{
    this->coef = coef;
    this->expo = expo;
    this->next = next;
}
};
//
class LinkedList
{
public:
Node *head;
int size;
LinkedList()
{
    head = new Node(0, 0, NULL);
    head->coef = 0;
    head->expo = 0;
    head->next = NULL;
    size = 0;
}
int degree();
int coefficient(int);
bool match(LinkedList *, LinkedList*);
void insert();
LinkedList sum(LinkedList *, LinkedList *);
LinkedList dot(LinkedList *, LinkedList *);
};LinkedList x, y, z;
```

I have also defined memeber function like below:

```
bool LinkedList::match(LinkedList *expr1, LinkedList *expr2)
{
// Check if both expressions have a same length
if (expr1->size != expr2->size)
{
    cout << "The expressions do not match in length." << endl;
    return false;
}
else if (expr1->size == expr2->size)
{
    // Both expressions are the same in length, but not equal
    while (expr1->head->coef && expr2->head->coef)
}
}
```

Problem is I can not access the nodes inside the expr1 and expr2 which are the pointer pointing to the beginning of the expr1 and expr2
Any help?

Comment: is Node definition in the same file as LinkedList.h and LinkedList.cpp is including .h file? it looks as if the Node definition was inaccessible in match() function

Comment: The definition of both Node and LinkedList class are in the same file named LinkedList.h; and that is #included inside the LinkedList.cpp file containing member function definition.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. What is the error message?

Comment: @mehdix_ please paste complete .h and .cpp files

Comment: Problem is I am not able to access the nodes inside the expressions. or maybe I have not enough knowledge how to make that it work.

Comment: What I need to do is loop over the sequence of nodes to which expr1 and 2 are pointing.

Comment: @mehdix_ and what is exact error message?

Comment: @computer That I think I'm going the wrong way. would you help if you think it is correct?

Comment: "What I need to do is loop over" => You forgot the loop?

Comment: @mehdix_ please insert full code of .h and .cpp files, you can paste it on http://pastebin.com/

Comment: @M.E.L how to make that happen? I'm not sure that If I was accessing the correct data.

Comment: @computer http://pastebin.com/KUtW90cT

Comment: ok, for me it compiles: just correct while statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just correct the while statement

```
    while (expr1->head->coef && expr2->head->coef) {
        // do something                            ^
    }
    ^
```

also make sure `Node` is accessible from `LinkedList.cpp` (so it is for istance in `LinkedList.h` that this cpp includes)

the error was:

> main.cpp: In member function ‘bool LinkedList::match(LinkedList*,
>   LinkedList*)’: main.cpp:78: error: expected primary-expression before
>   ‘}’ token main.cpp:78: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token

also you don't need `#include <conio.h>` here

Comment: Did you see the code? wouldn't it be frustrating to access the nodes inside the list dereferencing twice?

Comment: this is your code, please just correct this while statement and your problem should be resolved. I took your code and compiled it, it works

Comment: I understand! but is there any other way around to access the nodes inside without dereferencing twice?

Comment: no, since the head is a pointer, you have to dereference it to get data behind it, you might write while (*(expr1->head).coef && *(expr2->head).coef) {} however if this notation suits you better